# Why this code gives error? It uses parenthesis in multi line macros.I found this on an article in GeeksforGeeks

Tags: c

This is my program. Why this code gives error? It uses parenthesis in multi line macros.I found this on an article in GeeksforGeeks

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MACRO(num, str) ({\
            printf("%d", num);\
            printf(" is");\
            printf(" %s number", str);\
            printf("\n");\
           })

int main(void)
{
    int num;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if (num & 1)
        MACRO(num, "Odd");
    else
        MACRO(num, "Even");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is giving correct answer.

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: That it is an excellent example of bad formatting?

Comment: It's saying "expected an expression" while highlighting "MACRO"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using clang, the code actually compiles, but it gives some warnings. The warnings are generated because of the parenthesis and braces in the macro definition, or - to be more exact - because of the lack of braces in the if-else statement. You can rewrite the code to the following form:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MACRO(num, str) \
        printf("%d", num);\
        printf(" is");\
        printf(" %s number", str);\
        printf("\n");

int main(void)
{
    int num;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if (num & 1)
    {
        MACRO(num, "Odd");
    }
    else
    {
        MACRO(num, "Even");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can further simplify your code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MACRO(num, str) printf("%d is %s number\n", num, str);

int main(void)
{
    int num;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if (num & 1)
    {
        MACRO(num, "Odd");
    }
    else
    {
        MACRO(num, "Even");
    }
    return 0;
}
```